# Declare String in class or method

Tags: java, string

I just started thinking about this but can not come up with whats best. The string declared will only be used in one method and will never be changed. Should the string be declared in the method or as static final in the class?

Example in class:

```
public class DBHandler {
     final String sqlInsertHouse = "INSERT INTO " tableName + " VALUES (?,?)";

     public void insertHouse(String name, String type) {
          //use sqlInsertHouse string in query.
     }
}
```

Example in method:

```
public class DBHandler {

     public void insertHouse(String name, String type) {
          final String sqlInsertHouse = "INSERT INTO " tableName + " VALUES (?,?)";
          //use sqlInsertHouse string in query.
     }
}
```

So which one should I use? If it depends on the situation then please give some examples.

Comment: Why declare it at all? Just place it inline at the use site.

Comment: Sorry, just edited it.

Comment: does your tableName variable get change time to time?

Comment: Inline makes the code much less readable so I rather avoid that option.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne It may be, but it is used in multiple querys so to avoid String errors I defined it in only one place.

Comment: how `tableName` is defiend?

Comment: In your first method since you don't have declared tableName variable you probably get compile errors. Are you always going to insert just 2 values for each and every table? I think having an query string like this is not necessary at all. You can use inline string when ever you want to use them.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't be that bothered, either is fine. It's best to be consistent though and given that some queries may be run by more than one method I would go with the class declaration. But really there are probably more important things to worry about. ;)

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne yeah I know, in the real code there is a much larger set of queries and tables. This is just an example to make the question visual. Not to be compilable code.

Comment: Use String variable inside method if you are not expecting to call this method again and again. Advantage of this is that after method completion variable will be removed. Whereas instance variable remains until its object exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how often it will be called.

If you declare it outside of the method then Javas [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) will flag it and surround it with locking code when compiled to byte code, meaning it is less efficient.

Declaring it inside the method will create a new String every time it is called, which could be just as inefficient if it is called a lot.

So basically either way is fine, these are just things to be aware of.  To spot which is faster you'd probably need to profile it.

**Also**

Your code wont compile.  ;)

Comment: So just out of curiosity, what would be the most efficient way to deal with this?

Comment: Really I think the difference will be small but you'd need to profile it to find out whether it's quicker to recreate the object every time or execute the locking code.

Personally I would go with the intra-method approach, simply because it's the only place it's used.